# What is the name of the 3 word address system?

Tags: geocoding, what3words

I remember this system(website) from a couple of years ago, but I don't remember the name.  But the general idea is that you could identify any location on the earth with 3 words.  IIRC, there was no actual data available but there was a paid web API.

What was this website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The website is called [what3words](http://what3words.com/) which says on its website that:

> what3words is a unique combination of just 3 words that identifies a
>   3mx3m square, anywhere on the planet.
>
> It’s far more accurate than a postal address and it’s much easier to
>   remember, use and share than a set of coordinates.

This capability is now integrated [within the ArcGIS platform as a locator](http://esri.what3words.com/) and it is also available for QGIS (see [Does QGIS have any plugin to work with WhatThreeWords?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/179274/115)).

Comment: Random trivia - the location `geographic.information.system` is located in Antarctica on their system

Comment: Also QGIS: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179274/does-qgis-have-any-plugin-to-work-with-whatthreewords